# SqlDatasource select command is not selecting values from declared columns , it takes all columns that contain the input value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

I'm trying to select values from some columns with sqldatasource.select command but instead of selecting the values from the declared columns to search , it seletects all columns that have the value searched.Also,the value is highlighted when is found.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                foreach (TableCell rws in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    if (rws.Controls.Count == 0)
                    {
                        rws.Text = rws.Text.Replace(search.text, "<span style='background-color:#FFFF00;'>" + search.text + "</span>");
                    }
                }
             }
 }
```

The button1 select command:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * FROM TTBs where Name like '%" + search.text + "%' or Age like '%" + search.text + "%' or Birthday like '%" + search.text + "%'";
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Never, ever, ever, ever concatenate user input into SQL. Did I mention ever? ("SQL Injection") Any user could destroy your DB at the moment just using the search. In other news, concatenating user input into html *also* isn't a great idea ("XSS") - in this case not an interesting attack, as it would largely be self-inflicted harm.

Comment: Is this a case-sensitivity issue, perhaps? what is an example `search.text`, and what is example data in the database?

Comment: what do you mean by concatenating

Comment: concatenation is joining strings together; the `... like '%" + search.text + "%' or ...` is ***incredibly*** dangerous. That should be parameterized if you value the ongoing existence of your database. However, my question about example data and example `search.text` still stands.

Comment: search.text is a textbox where I search in gridview , and what do you mean by data example

Comment: yes, I guessed it was a textbox or similar - that doesn't change anythingl it is still really really deadly. By an example, I mean along the lines of "I am searching for the word `blue` and there is a record with `Name` = `'The Blue Danube'`"

Comment: it must show all rows wich contain in the searched column that word, the word in each row is highlighted

Comment: my goal is to search text in some columns and highlight the found word in rows

Comment: since this is a filter, **all** rows will contain the text you are looking for. You aren't making your intent very clear at all.

Comment: ohh, well , can you help me with making a search function please, I've searched on google but none of the examples worked for me .ty